# How to get exe application name and version in C# Compact Framework

Tags: c#, compact-framework, versioning

My application has an exe and uses some DLLs. I am writing all in C#.

In one DLL I want to write a method to get the application name and version from the version information in the exe.

I understand that in full .NET I could use GetEntryAssembly, but that that is unavailable in CF.

Comment: Did you try `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.ModuleName` ? That was what **I** was looking for when I stumbled upon your question.

Comment: @mini-me It's too long ago to remember

Comment: @Bitterblue System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule is not availble in CF.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Getting the app name:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;
```

Getting the version:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
```

You might want to use `GetCallingAssembly()` or getting the assembly by type (e.g. `typeof(Program).Assembly`) if your DLL is trying to get the EXE version and you don't have immediate access to it.

**EDIT**

If you have a DLL and you need the name of the executable you have a few options, depending on the use case.  You can get the Assembly from a type contained in the EXE assembly, but since it would be rare for the DLL to reference the EXE, it requires the EXE pass in an object of that type.

```
Version GetAssemblyVersionFromObjectType(object o)
{
    o.GetType().Assembly.GetName().Version;
}
```

You could also do a little bit of an end-run like this:

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int GetModuleFileName(IntPtr hModule, StringBuilder lpFilename, int nSize);

...

var name = new StringBuilder(1024);
GetModuleFileName(IntPtr.Zero, name, 1024);
var version = Assembly.LoadFrom(name.ToString()).GetName().Version;
```

Comment: GetExecutingAssembly() will get the name of the DLL it is called from. I want the name of the exe.

Comment: GetCallingAssembly() is more complicated and can have unexpected results.

Comment: Please explain "getting the assembly by type (e.g. typeof(Program).Assembly)"

Answer (score 27):

`System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Version;`

This function will give version of Application from where other libraries are loaded.

`System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;`

This will give version of current library. If you call this in Application library you will get application version and if call this in a DLL then will get that DLL version.

So in my opinion `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Version;`
is currect function to use.

Comment: GetExecutingAssembly() is not available in Compact Framework!

Answer (score 18):

If you want to create a component (.dll) use into another app reference to fetch the main app name and version, you can use this way:

Get the main app name:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainManager.EntryAssembly.GetName().Name;
```

Get the version:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainManager.EntryAssembly.GetName().Version.ToString();
```

Get the FullName (contain: app name, app version, culture, publicKeyToken):

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainManager.EntryAssembly.FullName;
```

But in this solution there is a problem, that's dependent on the host and if it runs directly from the executable file, the error will occur.
Therefore the following elections:

Get the main app name:

```
string appName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName;
appName = appName.Substring(0, appName.IndexOf('.'));
```

Get the version:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.ProductVersion;
```

Comment: I don't think this answer is getting enough credit.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me

```
var versionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);
string version = versionInfo.FileVersion;
```

This gets the version of the current running EXE, regardless if this string is called from a DLL/other project linked, etc

Comment: Disregard. There are far better ways. eg. Application.AssemblyName etc

Answer (score -6):

Can you try using `FileInfo` Class `FileVersionInfo`. Hope this will help..

You can also try Win32 API like GetModuleFile()

Comment: wat you are looking to say here?

Comment: I'm with cja on this. It's most helpful to have code examples with answers like this.