# Retrieve a Version Number from a Path

Tags: c#, path

I have a path that looks like the following:

> C:\Program Files\AnsysEM\AnsysEm16.0\Win64

I am particularly interested in getting the "16.0" portion of the path. Is there a good way of doing this?

I was thinking of splitting the path, and extracting numbers from the 3rd element in the array. However, I am not sure how robust of a solution this is, or if there is a better way of doing this.

***EDIT***:

For a little more background, I am getting paths from the registry to determine the location of a couple of exe's. The paths I get are in the form shown above. I need to write these file locations as Environment Variable.

So, if the version is 16.0, I would write something in the registry like: DIR_16_0 with the value of it being the path.

Comment: This might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14829689/how-to-get-exe-application-name-and-version-in-c-sharp-compact-framework

Comment: Are you trying to get the version of an installed application?

Comment: @Kurubaran I didn't think of possibly getting the version from the exe...I might try that. It might be more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hacky, but you can search the string from the regex '\d+.\d+' to match anything of form XXX+.XXX+

```
var rg = new Regex(@"\d+\.\d+");
var matches = regex.Match(path);
var versionNumber = match.Groups.FirstOrDefault() //eg.
```